# Bash FTP Backup Script

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, backup

I run the following script on my server:

```
#!/bin/bash
# System + MySQL backup script
# Full backup day - Fri (rest of the day do incremental backup)
# Copyright (c) 2005-2006 nixCraft <http://www.cyberciti.biz/fb/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# Automatically generated by http://bash.cyberciti.biz/backup/wizard-ftp-script.php
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

### System Setup ###
DIRS="/var/www /etc"
BACKUP=/tmp/backup.$$
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
INCFILE="/root/tar-inc-backup.dat"
DAY=$(date +"%a")
FULLBACKUP="Fri"

### MySQL Setup ###
MUSER="xxx"
MPASS="xxx"
MHOST="localhost"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

### FTP server Setup ###
FTPD="/backup/incremental"
FTPU="xxx"
FTPP="xxx"
FTPS="xxx"
NCFTP="$(which ncftpput)"

### Other stuff ###
EMAILID="xxx"

### Start Backup for file system ###
[ ! -d $BACKUP ] && mkdir -p $BACKUP || :

### See if we want to make a full backup ###
if [ "$DAY" == "$FULLBACKUP" ]; then
  FTPD="/backup/full"
  FILE="fs-full-$NOW.tar.gz"
  tar -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
else
  i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
  FILE="fs-i-$NOW-$i.tar.gz"
  tar -g $INCFILE -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
fi

### Start MySQL Backup ###
# Get all databases name
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
 FILE=$BACKUP/mysql-$db.$NOW-$(date +"%T").gz
 $MYSQLDUMP -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done

### Dump backup using FTP ###
#Start FTP backup using ncftp
ncftp -u"$FTPU" -p"$FTPP" $FTPS<<EOF
mkdir $FTPD
mkdir $FTPD/$NOW
cd $FTPD/$NOW
lcd $BACKUP
mput *
quit
EOF

### Find out if ftp backup failed or not ###
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
 rm -f $BACKUP/*
 T=/tmp/backup.pass
 echo "Date: $(date)">$T
 echo "Hostname: $(hostname)" >>$T
 echo "Backup passed" >>$T
 mail  -s "BACKUP PASSED" "$EMAILID" <$T
 rm -f $T
else
 T=/tmp/backup.fail
 echo "Date: $(date)">$T
 echo "Hostname: $(hostname)" >>$T
 echo "Backup failed" >>$T
 mail  -s "BACKUP FAILED" "$EMAILID" <$T
 rm -f $T
fi
```

Everything is working well, except that it always tells me everything went well, even tho the remote ftp server is full. Can someone help me changing this, so it gives me an error, when the remote server is full?
Also, is there any way to remove old backups?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: my experience is that you need an extra layer of processing whose only role is to check that the everything is OK, possibly storing the output of `dir` and `ldir` commands into arrays and comparing, line by line. FTP clients have lots of variability, so you might have one that will have something equivalent to the `df` cmd, but not likely. Also, testing of every error condition may reveal that your ftp client will return an error code when 'local file not found', or 'can't write to remote', etc, but you still face the fact that different ftp servers/client will respond differently. Good luck.

Comment: eh-hm... and er... you might find some helpful stuff by reviewing answers of mine by searching with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A620097+ftp . Good luck. ;-)